# How do custom methods in JpaRepository interface work?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

in my Spring Boot projects I use custom methods in repository which I can fold up using IntelliJ suggestions.

Example:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository  extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer>
{
    List<Book> getAllByAuthor_IdAuthorAndCategory_IdCategoryOrderByTitleASC(int idAuthor, int idCategory);

}
```

Where Book's model looks:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_book")
    private int idBook;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_author", referencedColumnName = "id_author")
    private Author author;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_category", referencedColumnName = "id_category")
    private Category category;

    public Book() {}

    // Setters and Getters....
}
```

And it actually work excellent without any configuration or additional classes! It is so simple and usefull... but how does it work? I can't find any documentation or tutorial about this function in JpaRepository. I discovered it by accident. I'd appreciate for any information. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

In `SpringDataJpa` JPA knows the table name, the columns, and the columns' data types all by looking at your entity annotations, attributes, and attribute data types.

For custom queries , there is something DSL(Domain Specific Language) which helps Spring Data JPA to work effectively with JPA.

For more information, check this https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-spring-data-jpa/